# How to avoid the cursor and what is the other way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I am using the cursor in my stored procedure; I am hoping to remove the cursor from my SP. Please help me come up with a solution for how to avoid the cursor statement to normal update statement with dynamic.

Example Below:

1. `Update Tablename set columnname(variable) = value from table A join Table B on A.condition = B.Condition where name = 'Test'(variable) and age = 18(variable)`
2. `Update Tablename set columnname(variable) = value from table A join Table B on A.condition = B.Condition where name = 'kumar'(variable) and age = 19(variable)`
3. `Update Tablename set columnname(variable) = value from table A join Table B on A.condition = B.Condition where name = 'babu'(variable) and age = 30(variable)`

This is how my cursor will work. 300 Combination dynamically pick the data from table and update into the main table

I am trying to take out the cursor, and update statement should work similar to this, instead of writing 300 update statements, I want to write one update where all the 300 combinations should execute.

Below is my code which needs this solution:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(100)           
  DECLARE @TargetColumn VARCHAR(100)           
  DECLARE @SourceColumn VARCHAR(100)           
  DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)        

  DECLARE a_cursor CURSOR STATIC           
  FOR          
  SELECT [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn] FROM  ref.tblEdsMap        
  GROUP BY [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn]         
  OPEN a_cursor          
  FETCH NEXT FROM a_cursor INTO @Type,@SourceColumn,@TargetColumn      
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0          
  BEGIN          


  SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  GCT SET GCT.' + @TargetColumn + ' = map.[TargetValue]       
   from  EdsMap map      
   JOIN Table GCT      
   ON GCT.' + @SourceColumn + ' = map.[SourceValue]       
   where map.[Type]=''' + @Type + ''' and map.SourceColumn=''' + @SourceColumn+ ''''       
  Exec (@SQL)        
  PRINT @SQL        
  FETCH NEXT FROM a_cursor INTO @Type,@SourceColumn,@TargetColumn      
  END          
  CLOSE a_cursor          
  DEALLOCATE a_cursor       
END
```

Comment: If you don't find a way to use a join you can improve your cursor by using FAST_FORWARD (essentially a combination of READ_ONLY and FORWARD_ONLY).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use an explicit cursor or a cursor cleverly disguised as a while loop, I prefer row concatenation operations for this type of problem.

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cmd += N'
   UPDATE GCT 
     SET GCT.' + QUOTENAME(TargetColumn) + ' = map.TargetValue     
     FROM dbo.EdsMap AS map 
     INNER JOIN dbo.Table AS GCT      
     ON GCT.' + QUOTENAME(SourceColumn) + ' = map.SourceValue    
   WHERE map.[Type] = ''' + [Type] + ''' 
   AND map.SourceColumn = ''' + [SourceColumn]+ ''';'
FROM ref.tblEdsMap
GROUP BY [Type], SourceColumn, TargetColumn;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've done these in the past, I usually make up a transaction to encompass every update that's needed. Something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE #targets ([Type] VARCHAR(255),[SourceColumn] VARCHAR(255),[TargetColumn] VARCHAR(255));

    INSERT INTO #targets
            ( [Type], [SourceColumn], [TargetColumn] )       
    SELECT [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn] FROM  ref.tblEdsMap        
      GROUP BY [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn]; 

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = 'BEGIN TRAN'  + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);

    SELECT @sql = @sql + 
    'UPDATE  GCT SET GCT.' + [TargetColumn] + ' = map.[TargetValue]       
       from  EdsMap map      
       JOIN Table GCT      
       ON GCT.' + [SourceColumn] + ' = map.[SourceValue]       
       where map.[Type]=''' + [Type] + ''' and map.SourceColumn=''' + [SourceColumn]+ ''';' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
    FROM #targets   

    SELECT @sql = @sql + 'COMMIT TRAN'

    PRINT @sql

    Exec (@SQL)
```

The update statements are still the same, i.e., you get one update per combination. But now you're running as one transaction batch. You could potentially be fancier with the dynamic SQL, so that you had just one update statement, but in my experience, it's too easy to get bad updates that way.

Doing it this way may not be any faster than a cursor. You'd have to test to be sure. With the examples where I've used this approach, it *has* generally been a faster approach.

Comment: @ Jason - Thanks Surely i will test it today and let you know the same

Answer (score -2):

Try using a table variable along with a `WHILE` loop instead, like so:

```
 BEGIN

 DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(100)           
 DECLARE @TargetColumn VARCHAR(100)           
 DECLARE @SourceColumn VARCHAR(100)           
 DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)        

 DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE
 (
   ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Type varchar(100),
   SourceColumn varchar(100),
   TargetColumn varchar(100)
 )

 DECLARE @Count int, @Max int

 INSERT INTO @SomeTable (Type, SourceColumn, TargetColumn)
 SELECT [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn]
 FROM  ref.tblEdsMap        
 GROUP BY [Type],[SourceColumn],[TargetColumn]

 SELECT @Count = 1, @Max = COUNT(ID)
 FROM @SomeTable

 WHILE @Count <= @Max
 BEGIN

   SELECT
        @Type = Type, 
        @SourceColumn = SourceColumn, 
        @TargetColumn = TargetColumn
   FROM @SomeTable
   WHERE ID = @Count  

   -- Your code
   SET @SQL = 'UPDATE  GCT SET GCT.' + @TargetColumn + ' = map.[TargetValue]       
   from  EdsMap map      
   JOIN Table GCT      
   ON GCT.' + @SourceColumn + ' = map.[SourceValue]       
   where map.[Type]=''' + @Type + ''' and map.SourceColumn=''' + @SourceColumn+ ''''       
   Exec (@SQL)        
   PRINT @SQL        

   SET @Count = @Count + 1

 END     -- while

 END
```

Comment: Why do you think a while loop isn't a cursor?

Comment: They are similar, but this method I've found is a LOT more performant.

Comment: [I haven't found any such thing](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx). A while loop is a cursor without saying `DECLARE CURSOR` explicitly. And I suspect introducing the table variable might actually make it slower.

Comment: I think in this scenario you can use inner join.

Comment: @Sonam I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. Could you post an answer demonstrating how you'll use an INNER JOIN for an UPDATE where column names are populated dynamically and come from a table?

Comment: My table data size is 9.5 Million records which i need to update 30 column with 300 combination over all,  ex one update statement one combination similar like i have 300 comnination to update all the 30 column in the main table , pls help me the best solution with quick output

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I've used this scenario to query large (say ~10 million row) tables. Instead of iterating through the table at large, I'm grabbing a smaller subset of the data in the in-memory table to play with it there; it avoids some of the disk IO cost of hitting the table which translates into nice performance vs a true cursor. Whether a while is a cursor *per se* or not to me is just semantics, this particular application of it has saved me lots of time in otherwise extremely long-running queries.

Comment: @Darth Continent Thanks for your Quick help , however i will test and let you know the same ,

Comment: @user2614383: Welcome, hope it's helpful, performance-wise it should hopefully be a step up.

Comment: @Darth Continent - Have one small question compare to cursor query , which you have given the query is faster then cursor query ? also how is the speed ?

Comment: @Venki: Yes, I've found that in comparing this query using a WHILE loop to a (true) cursor for the same query operations over the same tables, the WHILE was *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks Darth Continent

Comment: Did you compare to [a cursor that uses lower-resource options than the default, like `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)? Again, A WHILE LOOP IS A CURSOR.

Comment: @Venki why don't YOU test it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  - Today i will check and let you know the performance of while loop

Comment: @AaronBertrand  - Today i will check and let you know the performance of while loop , In meanwhile if you don't mind could you please let me know what is FAST_FORWARD ? i have't heard this word and i didn't use,if you exp-lane so that going forward i could start using

Comment: @Venki please read these (linked above): http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help